How to increase max file upload size for Laravel Octane?
I can't upload file larger than 2MB while running Laravel 11 on Octane.
Without Octane it works so it does not seem to be problem with Nginx or PHP. I tried Frankenphp and Swoole and both failed to upload file. How can I increase this limit? From where is it configured?

By default, Swoole package size limit is 2MB. You can customize this from Laravel by changing the config package_max_length under swoole -> options in your octane.php
// config/octane.php

'swoole' => [
    'options' => [
        'log_file' => storage_path('logs/swoole_http.log'),
        'package_max_length' => 10 * 1024 * 1024, // 10 MB
    ],
],

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/octane#swoole-configuration

In case you need to customize Swoole more, here is a link with the full list of options : https://openswoole.com/docs/modules/swoole-server/configuration#list-of-configurations

For frankenphp I have found out that you can place php.ini in the same folder as frankenphp binary and it will use its values.
